# terrainに生やす木の当たり判定について

Tags: unity3d

初心者ですが宜しくおねがいします。

terrainで使うブラシ機能で生やす木、その木をmayaで作り、インポートしました。
生やすこと自体はできたのですが、当たり判定について悩んでいます。

カプセルコライダーなら当たり判定は付き、問題ありませんが木の形が少し特殊なのでメッシュコライダーのように密着した当たり判定にしたいのです。
しかしメッシュコライダーを使用するとterrain上で生やした木には当たり判定がつきません。（プレハブ上では当たり判定はつきます）
カプセルコライダーでないといけないのでしょうか？？

Answer (score 0):

カプセルコライダーでないといけないわけではないですが、
カプセルなど複数のコライダーを上手く配置してそれらしくするのが良いでしょう。

木：幹部分に判定を配置
草：通常の判定は行わず、ニーアオートマタみたく走りが解除されるよろめく特殊判定（要自作）を配置するとよいかも？

Comment: なるほど、回答ありがとうございます！
海外の方も調べたりしたのですが、私の英語力だとあまり見つけられなくて困ってました。